# I am trying to figure out how to create a method to set the primary key on a datatable

Tags: vb.net, methods, datatable, primary-key

I want to be able to pass one or more strings that are names of columns. The method would then set those column(s) as the primary key.

code in progress

```
public sub setPK(ParamArray columnNames As String())
    Dim primaryKeyColumns As List(Of System.Data.DataColumn)
    For Each s As String In columnNames
        primaryKeyColumns.Add(dataTable.Columns(s))
    Next
    dataTable.PrimaryKey = New System.Data.DataColumn() {primaryKeyColumns}
End Sub
```

I would appreciate any help/suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Public Sub setPK(ParamArray columnNames As String())
    Dim primaryKeyColumns(columnNames.Count - 1) As System.Data.DataColumn
    For i As Integer = 0 To columnNames.Count - 1 Step 1
        primaryKeyColumns(i) = dataTable.Columns(columnNames(i))
    Next
    dataTable.PrimaryKey = primaryKeyColumns
End Sub
```